# Get the 'Out of the office' status

Tags: c#, outlook

I am making an console application that sends mails to users that must do some moves on an other client application.

This works.

The thing is, I want to avoid sending the mail, if this user has a 'out of the office' message enable on its outlook box (the mail client of the mail will always be outlook).

But I do not found a way to check if the 'out of the office' message is enable or not, either with `outlook interop`, or `MailMessage`.

As a 'out of the office' message is send only the first time, I have to know the status.

First, what I'm asking will be easier with interop or MailMessage?
Second, Can I do it?

Comment: Isn't out of office an after the fact reply

Comment: Well, it is a setting in Outlook, so can't we know, with the email address, if it is enable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redemption (I am its author) and its [RDOOutOfOfficeAssistant](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOOutOfOfficeAssistant.htm) object, but it requires to open the user's mailbox first.
You can use also straight EWS and its [GetUserOofSettingsRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa493825%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) verb.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about MailMessage, but I'd go with outlook interop for sure! As long you send the mails from within the same network you should be alright!

Comment: The thing is, an 'out of the office message, will show only the first time, so I need to know if it is enable. Not check if I got an mail in return.*

Comment: Can't you just deactivate your mails for x number of days once you know you've got a reply?

Comment: Desactivate my mails? I can possibly contact 20 users or more per day. Without knowing when they come back. That why I need to check the status 'out of the office' when I try to send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to use MailTips in Exchange Web Services (EWS) to get a mail user's out-of-office status.  This code snippet uses a service account on the Exchange side that can read an arbitrary user's account info.  (If you get an access denied response, you may need to ask your Exchange admin to enable impersonation on the account.)  If you just want to test the code, you can specify your own domain account for the credentials and request the out-of-office status of your own account.

```
// Returns the user's out-of-office message, or null if the user does not have out-of-office set.
public static string GetUserOutOfOfficeMessage(string userEmailAddress)
{
    const string outOfOfficeRequestMessageTemplate =
       @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
                        xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""
                        xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""
                        xmlns:t=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"">
            <soap:Header>
                <t:RequestServerVersion Version=""Exchange2010""/>
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
                <GetMailTips xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"">
                <SendingAs>
                    <t:EmailAddress>{0}</t:EmailAddress>
                    <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType></SendingAs>
                    <Recipients>
                    <t:Mailbox>
                        <t:EmailAddress>{1}</t:EmailAddress>
                        <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
                    </t:Mailbox>
                    </Recipients>
                <MailTipsRequested>OutOfOfficeMessage</MailTipsRequested>
                </GetMailTips>
            </soap:Body>
         </soap:Envelope>";

    string exchangeServiceUrl = "https://.../Exchange.asmx";  // get the full URL from your Exchange admin
    WebRequest exchangeServiceRequest = WebRequest.Create(exchangeServiceUrl);
    HttpWebRequest exchangeSoapServiceRequest = (HttpWebRequest)exchangeServiceRequest;
    exchangeSoapServiceRequest.Method = "POST";
    exchangeSoapServiceRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    exchangeSoapServiceRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    exchangeSoapServiceRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(serviceAccountUserName, 
        serviceAccountPassword, yourDomain);  // for serviceAccountUserName try either login name or email address
    exchangeSoapServiceRequest.Timeout = 60000;
    Stream exchangeSoapServiceRequestStream = exchangeSoapServiceRequest.GetRequestStream();

    using (StreamWriter exchangeServiceWriter = new StreamWriter(exchangeSoapServiceRequestStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        string outOfOfficeMessageRequest = string.Format(
            outOfOfficeRequestMessageTemplate, serviceAccountUserName, userEmailAddress);

        try
        {
            exchangeServiceWriter.Write(outOfOfficeMessageRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log something
        }
        finally
        {
            exchangeServiceWriter.Close();
        }
    }

    string outOfOfficeResponse = null;
    string userOutOfOfficeMessage = null;

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse exchangeServiceResponse = (HttpWebResponse)exchangeSoapServiceRequest.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader exchangeServiceResponseStream = new StreamReader(exchangeServiceResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            outOfOfficeResponse = exchangeServiceResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log something
    }

    if (outOfOfficeResponse != null)
    {
        const int messageElementStartTagLength = 11;
        int messageStartIndex = outOfOfficeResponse.IndexOf("<t:Message>");

        if (messageStartIndex >= 0)
        {
            int messageEndIndex = outOfOfficeResponse.IndexOf("</t:Message>");

            if (messageEndIndex >= 0)
            {
                int outOfOfficeMessageLength = messageEndIndex - messageStartIndex;

                // Adjust for length of the <t:message> tag itself so that we don't include the tag in the output.
                messageStartIndex += messageElementStartTagLength;
                outOfOfficeMessageLength -= messageElementStartTagLength;

                userOutOfOfficeMessage = outOfOfficeResponse.Substring(messageStartIndex, outOfOfficeMessageLength);
            }
        }
    }

    return userOutOfOfficeMessage;
}
```